# Konsole does not execute .profile or .bash_profile

Tags: 12.04, bash, .profile, konsole

When I open `Konsole` the settings in `.profile` are not executed, and it means the `~/bin` is not added to the `PATH`.

Is there a way to get `Konsole` to do that?

PS. Is there a way to tell whether Konsole is running `bash` or `dash`

Answer (score 5):

These files: `.profile` or `.bash_profile` are executed by the command interpreter only for **login shells**. See what is [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175/37944)

To execute, for example, `.profile` file in your konsole after you open it, run the following command:

```
source ~/.profile
```

or:

```
. ~/.profile
```

These commands are equivalent and they source/execute the code from inside of `~/.profile` file.

Comment: Is there a way to get Konsole to execute the required commands every time I run it?

Comment: @vfclists To source `~/.profile` in your `~/.bashrc` file will be wrong, because `~/.profile` is sourcing `~/.bashrc`. But, when you log in graphically, `~/.profile` will be specifically sourced, so any change that you make in this file will take effect next time when you log in. Only if you don't want to logging out and in again you have to run `source ~/.profile` every time when you open Konsole.

Comment: The problem is although `~/.profile` may be executed for the graphical shell the settings in it don't get passed on to new instances of `Konsole` so I will be to place those commands directly in `.bashrc` then.

Comment: in Settings -> Edit Current Profile -> General -> Command, change to:

/bin/bash -l

Comment: @SSJ_GZ I wonder why this is not the default